# 100% CPU usage with zeromq Push socket with 0 listeners

Tags: haskell, zeromq

I am currently in the process of implementing a communication pipeline between several processes using ZeroMQ, all using the Push/Pull mechanism. The pipeline starts with a 'ventilator' that generates tasks, and here is where my problem also starts: ZeroMQ seems to be using 100% CPU load when no workers are connected.

Here is the code in question, which attempts to send just one message:

```
module Main where

import System.ZMQ4.Monadic
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack)

main :: IO ()
main = do
     runZMQ $ do
            publisher <- socket Push
            bind publisher "tcp://*:10150"

            send publisher [] (pack "foo")

            close publisher
```

As you can see, this code is extremely simple and just attempts to send the message "foo" to any subscriber. I would expect this code to queue this message in the background, but instead it appears to get into a never-ending loop with the `send` command. Setting a high water mark on the socket has no effect.

There is an example in the zguide that is similar to what I'm trying to achieve: https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/Haskell/taskvent.hs

In this example, they explicitly request user input to start sending (specifically, 'press enter when workers are ready') -- is this the way they work around this problem?

Can anyone enlighten me what I'm doing wrong here, or what the best approach to solve this problem is?

**EDIT**

To elaborate, the following program (with a connected listener) works perfectly:

```
module Main where

import System.ZMQ4.Monadic
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack, unpack)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))

main :: IO ()
main = do
     runZMQ $ do
            publisher <- socket Push
            receiver  <- socket Pull

            bind    publisher "tcp://*:10150"
            connect receiver "tcp://127.0.0.1:10150"

            send publisher [] (pack "foo")    
            message <- unpack <$> receive receiver

            liftIO $ putStrLn ("received data: " ++ message)
```

This prints out the received data as expected.

**EDIT 2**

Using strace, I was able to decipher that apparently zeromq is in a poll/select infinite loop:

```
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
--- SIGVTALRM {si_signo=SIGVTALRM, si_code=SI_TIMER, si_pid=0, si_uid=0, si_value=0} ---
rt_sigreturn()                          = 1
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 1, 0)     = 0 (Timeout)
select(9, [], [8], NULL, NULL)          = 1 (out [8])
--- SIGVTALRM {si_signo=SIGVTALRM, si_code=SI_TIMER, si_pid=0, si_uid=0, si_value=0} ---
rt_sigreturn()                          = 1
```

and this pattern repeats itself endlessly.

Comment: I also submitted this as an actual issue for the library developers: https://github.com/twittner/zeromq-haskell/issues/55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 100% CPU usage has been confirmed as a bug by the library author. It is fixed in this commit:

https://github.com/twittner/zeromq-haskell/commit/4a6bc238dcc81cee4c8407c32edb018e371ab1e4

Answer (score 2):

### ZeroMQ architecture is not just-another-socket-wrapper

The first thing, Pieter Hintjens, the co-father of ZeroMQ series, recommends is to **forget everything you might have used while handling sockets so far.**

That has many reasons.

The first of which is, that ZeroMQ makes for you a pair of new, abstract worlds, that you should understand "in-principle" to rather live in peace with than to struggle against - both a **micro-COSMOS** ( the internal mechanics, one shall somehow respect and live in accord with ) and a **MACRO-cosmos**, that constructs a very powerful set of Scaleable-Formal-Communication-Patterns, one may further harness and integrate into higher order distributed processing systems.

### So?

Due to **micro-COSMOS**, you could opt to benefit from a low-latency / high-performance practice to rather initiate `ZMQ Context` instance somewhere very early in the code and similarly `assign` / `setup` / `bind` / `connect` the wanted ZMQ-primitive elements' instances  ( sockets of a feasible ZMQ-primitive archetype ... `PUSH`/`PULL` given in your case ), than to setup/close/setup/close resources ad-hoc, the less in an endless loop.

ZeroMQ instances are not disposables, but rather assets for the system. Rethink the architecture and both the micro-COSMOS and MACRO-cosmos will deliver an immense work for you.

### Next

Due to MACRO-cosmos rules, the `PUSH` / `PULL` (distributed) Formal-Communication-Pattern assumes, that a message remains inside the `PUSH`-er's (internal) queue, until a `PULL`-er ( invisibly and out of the opponent's code-control ) handshakes and retrieves it.

That also means, that if your code attempts to

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
     runZMQ $ do
            -- PUSH side
            -- ^... beware the ZMQ uses a keyword PUB ( publish )
            --      BUT in a different pattern, very different pattern
            ...
            close publisher
```

the code bumps into a **micro-COSMOS** internality, where a default value for a **`ZMQ_LINGER`** ( default == -1 ) parameter of a ZMQ-socket causes the attempt to **`close`** to wait infinitely, until any other process retrieves any and all the un-consumed messages already en-queued inside the **`PUSH`**-er.

That alone explains both the initial objection and the ad-hoc observation in EDIT1, that in case of a "connected" `PULL`-er the endless ZMQ_LINGER waiting loop does not appear. Also the EDIT2 just visualises what an ommission to do so causes in the low-level {select|poll} looping.
Q.E.D.

### Final Note

Definitely worth a few days time and efforts to read through both of the Pieter Hintjens' books on ZeroMQ.

Ultimate heap of gems and best practices there.

Much better than to strike a few one-liners in a trial-error loop

( As you have made the code bang into a principal dead-end, the "problem" is rather in your code, not in the ZMQ-haskel binding )

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. From your answer, I understand you're saying that the `close` command is responsible for the endless loop; yet the endless loop occurs at the `send` command. If I remove the `close` statement from the code, the end result is still the same.

Comment: Furthermore, as you said, it is supposed to enqueue the message when there are no subscribers (in this case, PULL). Can you explain to me why it goes into an endless loop at the `send` command, instead of the `close` command?